# Can't build yuvlib library function by visual stduio in cpp file

Tags: c++, c, .lib, libyuv

I builded and used libyuv in visual studio 2017.
I can build libyuv.h and function in c file.
but **If i change *main.c* file to *main.cpp* file then I cant build in cpp file.** can anyone help me?
i attached source/ refer to following link

https://github.com/stevenyeun/libyuvtest/tree/master/LibYuvTest/LibYuvTest

**here is main.cpp**

```
#include "libyuv.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "yuv.lib")

void main()
{
    NV12ToARGB(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

> error C3861: 'NV12ToARGB': identifier not found

I tried to add extern "C" keyword but cant build yet

Answer (score 1):

When compiled as C++ all functions are wrapped into `libyuv` namespace so invocation should look like `::libyuv::NV12ToARGB(nullptr,`

Comment: oh very thanks i didnt know it wrapped namespace...really appreciate^^